# Creating and enforcing has_one relationship in rails relational database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

Working on a table of viewed profiles. I kind of have an issue setting it up, is this correct? I am confused about the has_many and has_one relationship. Because this is one table that has a row for each visited relationship, I decided to go with has_one.

Does this look correct, also is there a way to enforce the relation in ActiveRecord?

## model

```
class ViewedProfile < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :viewed_profile_id, presence: true
  validates :profile_id, presence: true
  has_one :profile_id
  has_one :viewed_profile_id
end
```

## migration

```
class CreateViewedProfile < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :viewed_profiles do |t|
      t.integer :profile_id
      t.integer :viewed_profile_id
    end
  end
end
```

## edit

Also when I go to my console and I type ViewedProfile nothing comes up. Any idea as to why? =c the schema should normally show up!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, you are confused in between the terms **`Model`** names and **`attributes(specially Foreign keys)`**.Model will have **attributes** and the **associations** will be set to **models**.

You have to set your models like this

```
class ViewedProfile < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :profile
end

Class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :viewed_profile
  validates :viewed_profile_id, presence: true
  validates :viewed_profile_id, uniqueness: true
end
```

And your corresponding migration files should look like this

```
class CreateViewedProfile < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :viewed_profiles do |t|
      t.string :name
    end
  end
end

class CreateProfile < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :profiles do |t|
      t.integer :viewed_profile_id
    end
  end
end
```

I would recommend to read these Guides articles before getting started.

**[Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)**

**[Migrations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html)**

**[Validations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html)**

Comment: if `belongs_to` / `has_one` is truly the relationship you want you also need to add a unique index on `viewed_profile_id` of `profiles`, otherwise there's nothing to stop multiple `profiles` from having the same `viewed_profile_id`