# Enforce has_one relationship in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations, has-one

I am new to rails and am using the has_one association for the first time.

User Model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_one :shop_profile
validates :user_id, presence: true
validates :user_id, uniqueness: true
end
```

ShopProfile Model

```
class ShopProfile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

However I am still able to make multiple ShopProfiles per user. When a user makes a second shop_profile it removes the user_id from the first but there are still two in the database.

How do you limit the number of ShopProfiles a user can have to 1?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/23262570/429758

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have added the validatiosns as shown above but I do not get normal error messages such as with other validations. I get a full error page saying "Failed to remove the existing associated shop_profile. The record failed to save after its foreign key was set to nil." I would like to just have an error message show in a flash, how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails can't do this for you, it's up to you to find the existing record, or create a new one, and it's up to you to ensure that user's aren't creating second `ShopProfile` records. This shouldn't be a problem, you should be posting back to the correct action (`create` vs `update`) in the first place, based on the presence of an existing `ShopProfile` record for the user in question. You should be raising an error if a user with an existing `ShopProfile` attempts to post a new one to the `create` action.

---

Clarification based on your comments:

The problem here is that you're event letting users hit the creation form for profiles, if they already have a profile. Once a user has created a profile, if the act of creating a second profile is going to cause an error, users shouldn't be able to get themselves into this state in the first place. Once a user has a profile, you should be linking them to the **edit** view for that profile, not taking them back to the **create** view which will just yield an error once they've filled in the form.

That might look something like this:

```
<% if @user.shop_profile %>
  <%= link_to 'Edit Profile', [:edit, @user.shop_profile] %>
<% else %>
  <%= link_to 'Create Profile', new_shop_profile_path %>
<% end %>
```

If a user *does* somehow hit the "new" action to create a second profile, you should stop them immediately at that point, and refuse to render the creation form. Your `new` action should probably look something like this:

```
def new
  if @user.shop_profile
    redirect_to edit_shop_profile_path(@user.shop_profile)
  else
    @shop_profile = ShopProfile.new
  end
end
```

The alternative is that you need to provide users some way forward if they ask to create a new profile when they have an existing one. This might be a checkbox on your "create" form that lets them opt to *overwrite* their existing profile. The point is, you need to give them some way of *proceeding* through the various flows of your application, or else your application is basically broken. You should never back a user into a place where they're filling in a form with no actual way of successfully submitting it.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the guidance. It seems that the error I am getting is from using  @shop_profile = @user.build_shop_profile(shop_profile_params). I would like to just railse a normal error when a user attempts to create a second ShopProfile record, is this possible?

Comment: For example in the rails guides they give the example validates :name, uniqueness: { scope: :year,
    message: "should happen once per year" }. I would like to trigger a similar message such as "ShopProfile already exists"

Comment: You need to step back, there are larger problems here. You shouldn't be doing `@user.build_shop_profile` unless you're in the `create` action, and you shouldn't be able to hit the `create` action if a user already has a `ShopProfile`. You need to fix *that* larger problem. You should be in the `update` action if a user already has a `ShopProfile`, and then you should be doing `@user.shop_profile.update_attributes(shop_profile_params)`.

Comment: And no, there is no sane way to produce a validation error with Rails validations, because what you're trying to do **is not sane**. You need to fix the larger logic problems at play here.

Comment: Would that be simply removing the link to create a profile for users with an existing profile?

Comment: @Cu1ture Yes. If a user has an existing profile, you should link to the **edit** page for that profile. You should not be linking users to a "create profile" page if they already have one, and the act of creating a profile will just throw a validation error in their face. That's a terrible experience for your users, why set them on a path that they cannot actually proceed along in the first place, only to have them find out later after they have filled in a form?

Comment: Yes I agree, I am quite new to rails and am used to starting from the model and controllers and working back to the view when restricting users actions. I wasnt sure if just hiding the create link was robust enough. It seems I was overthinking the problem :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the best solution is to create profile after the registration so in your user model put this code

```
  has_one :profile, dependent: :destroy
  after_create :create_profile

  private

  def create_profile
    Profile.create(user: self)
  end
```